# How to Send Intent To Youtube App with Search Query and then play first video

Tags: android, android-intent, youtube

How to Send Intent To Youtube App with Search Query and **then play first video From Search Result** ,
In my app i need to send intent to youtube with search Query and then play First video Automatically once search Query is done , like google now is work with youtube

i send intent with Search Query it work fine, and  Youtube show me search Results but **now i want play First video from search Results Automatically**

this is my code to send intent to youtube

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH);
            intent.setPackage("com.google.android.youtube");
            intent.putExtra("query", matches.get(0));
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems impossible by using Intent (without using YouTube api). Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19714736/6950238) answer.